# htaccess problem 404 not found

Tags: .htaccess

I have rewrite URL like following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.example$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^a/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?searchtext=$1&locationtext=$2 [NC]
```

And I want to call my page like

```
http://kolkata.mydomain.example/a/phptraining/Kolkata
```

But when page is opening this is saying 404 not found. I’m not understanding this error.

Comment: What are you expecting it to rewrite to ?

Answer (score 0):

With this rule set only the first rule is probably applied but not the second. Try the first rule without *L* flag and consider a possible subdomain within the request path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.example$
RewriteRule .* /subdomain/$0
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1search.php?searchtext=$2&locationtext=$3 [NC]
```

Comment: this is running well for 3 parameters how ?