# Htaccess routing returns 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently, I tried using htaccess for my semantic cleaner urls. This is my code

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ home.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost/home.php?id=1` it returns the right thing but when I go to the `http://localhost/products/1` it returns a 404 not found error.

I tried the question: [htaccess rewrite returns 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223329/htaccess-rewrite-returns-404-not-found) and [htaccess problem 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223063/htaccess-problem-404-not-found) but nothing works

Comment: Try disabling multiviews `Options -Multiviews`  change `+` to `-` in the first line

Comment: still encountering the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
#rewrite /filename to /filename.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
# /product/123 to home.php?id=123
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ home.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Your rule returns a 404 when the requested URI is `/product/1` because your first rule rewrites it to an unknown location `/product/1.php` .  I added a condition in the first rule so it checks if the request is actually for a `.php` file.

Comment: Finally it worked! Thanks! But can u elaborate where I did wrong?